# How can I update probabilities if an event cannot occur?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

Suppose that I have general information (probabilities) for how many yards a football player will run on the football field.

Let $A$ be the event the runner goes 1 yards, $B$ the event the runner goes 2 yards, $C$ the event the runner goes 3 yards and $D$ the event the runner goes 4 yards.

Let $()=0.60$, $()=0.20$, $()=0.1$ and $P(D)=0.1$.

Now, let's assume the runner is actually only 2 yards away from the end zone and so the player cannot exceed 2 yards which means $P(C)$ and $P(D)$ cannot happen.

Also, if the player has gone 2 yards, that means that they went 1 yard, and if they player went 3 yards they also went 1 & 2 yards, etc.

My question is, in this scenario, how can $P(A), P(B)$ be updated to reflect this information?

Comment: The way it's written now, P(X=x) is the probability that the runner goes *exactly* x yards (not *at least* x yards), right? If the only options are now 1 and 2, then they must sum to 1. And their ratio is 3:1. Assuming you want those to stay the same, do you know how to take it from here?

Comment: So, you are looking for the [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) $P(A \mid A \cup B)$ and $P(B \mid A \cup B)$.  These should be easy to determine from the definition of conditional probability.